# How to set dhtmlXCombo option by value

Tags: javascript, combobox, dhtmlx

I have xml file like: 

    `<complete>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    </complete>`

And I have combobox, which is powered by this xml, and this combobox options are "A", "B", "C".

I want to set Combobox text to "A" through its value, so I use:

```
Combo.setComboValue(1);
```

And now my combo text is "1", not "A", but when I use:

```
alert();
Combo.setComboValue(1);
```

now my combo text is "A". Why? How can I set dhtmlXCombo option by value?

Comment: To inspect the problem, please provide a link to the demo where the issue can be reconstructed.

Answer (score 0):

use the selected=true attribute in your xml
 A or

After loading the options you can use the below statements
Combo.setComboValue("1");
Combo.setComboText("A");